# Get class of the date td selected in datepicker.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to change the CSS of the dates when they are selected on the basis of their css, specifically class names. But I am unable to get the class name of the `td`.

Any suggestions how can I get the class name? I tried `onSelect` and then used `.html()`, but it returns the whole HTML of `datepicker` as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the class name using

```
$('selector').attr('class');
```

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks for pointing out it.  I changed it and found the a good reason from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16654497/1671639

Comment: well I know this thing, but its datepicker.js, which generates everything dynamically and there is no id to any table or td

Answer (score -1):

you can get the class name by the following in Jquery

```
var className = $('#table_id .td').attr('class');
```

Comment: well I know this thing, but its datepicker.js, which generates everything dynamically and there is no id to any table or td